# Data needed for ISP to identify users

Tags: ip

If the following data is known:

1. URL of web site X,
2. Exact time and dates when the visit to web site X occurred,
3. Anonymized IP address of web site visitors (without the last digit, e.g. 125.251.101.x),

can ISP still determine/identify users who used its network to visit the web site X in given dates and times only based on this information or it needs the complete IP address?

Comment: Did these users use SecureDNS?  (I'm assuming Https is a given here?)

Comment: Https is used but not SecureDNS.

Answer (score 2):

To identify its client the ISP normally needs its full IP address. But... they may have their own logs. In fact, depending on the country, they may have to keep logs for some month in case of legal investigation.

In that use case, knowing the dates, and the destination site should be enough by comparing that information with what they have in their own logs (*exact* IP, date and destination). Once the exact IP is identified, they know which client is responsable, and can (must) give that for the legal action.

Comment: In my case, police subpoenaed ISP and they said they need the last digit of the IP address. To me it seems irrelevant because they are obligated by the law to retain every information to determine source and destination of communication, as well as date, time and duration. In addition, what difference does it make if they would have the last digit of the IP address given the fact it is public address used by hundreds of users behind it?

Comment: you're assuming the ISP wants to do the work necessary here... sounds like they don't want to check a specific time-frame for specific site access (including vpn traffic) and also have to check against 0-9. (or 0-255?) In general they have a separate division that handles this stuff, and they probably come back to the ISP with "we need the full IP" at first.  They won't be particularly eager to give up their customers' data.

Comment: But when the IP address is anonymized due to GDPR, there is no way around but to check according to dates, times and URL. I guess they are just lazy...

Comment: well, not sure about that.  ISPs have a lot of customers, and they may also have to check all the VPN and/or secureDNS traffic here.... not such an easy task.

Comment: @pcalkins If entire IP address is known, how much easier would it be? Since it is a dynamic public IP address with hundreds or even thousands of users behind it, they would still need to perform the search based on times, dates and URL, as well. I don't believe they can only perform search using IP address as the only criteria.

Comment: The ISP absolutely knows which customer uses which IP at any particular time.  They deliver that traffic to/from them.

Comment: @pcalkins Therefore, if they include times, dates and URL in the search, they can find all users which were communicating with that particular URL. The full IP address is not crucial in this case.

Comment: I think I may have misunderstood you a bit.  I guess this IP is coming from the web site, but they only store so much of it.  Someone else would have to answer whether that's enough to point to a particular ISP... I would think so.. and I guess at that point they could rule out VPN users.  Technically they should be able to check a database and come to some conclusions.  It's much harder without the full IP, though.  It's a bit intrusive to go through logs for 255 users.  I don't know whether their own privacy protection policy would allow it?

Comment: The IP is from the address range owned by particular ISP which needs to store information about source, destination, date, time, duration etc. by the law in case of investigation. ISP did not refer to any privacy policy, they only required the information about the last digit. But then again, it depends what exact data the police delivered to the ISP.

Comment: They may need a court order for John Doe's 0-255.  I think I'm still misunderstanding though.  Are you in contact with both the ISP and the Police here?

Comment: @pcalkins No, I am in contact only with the police which informed me about the ISP's reply to subpoena and their request for the fourth digit of IP address.